# How to return the highest value in a sequence for each ID unless one has been skipped, with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return the columns listed below but would like it grouped by JobNumber and only return the maximum StageNum so long as it has not skipped any stages.

For example, my table currently looks like this:

| ID | Stage | StageNum | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | Released | 10 | 2022-02-07 |
| 104 | Slab | 20 | 2022-02-18 |
| 104 | Frame | 30 | 2022-03-07 |
| 104 | Mechanicals | 42 | 2022-03-10 |
| 105 | Released | 10 | 2022-02-07 |
| 105 | Slab | 20 | 2022-02-18 |
| 106 | Released | 10 | 2022-02-07 |
| 106 | Slab | 20 | 2022-02-18 |
| 106 | Frame | 30 | 2022-03-04 |
| 106 | Cornice | 40 | 2022-03-08 |

And the result should look like this with ID 104 returning StageNum 30 instead of 42 since StageNum 40 was skipped:

| ID | Stage | StageNum | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | Frame | 30 | 2022-03-07 |
| 105 | Slab | 20 | 2022-02-18 |
| 106 | Cornice | 40 | 2022-03-08 |

I can return the highest value by grouping by ID and selecting MAX(StageNum) but do not know how to account for the skipped stages.

Comment: You need a table of stages (10, Released), ..  to compare your table with.

Comment: I see. That wouldn't be a problem to create but what would be the logic of comparing this table with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided there exists the `stages` table

```
select * into stages
from(
  values
   ('Released', 10),
   ('Slab',     20),
   ('Frame',    30),
   ('Mechanicals', 42),
   ('Cornice',     40)
) t(Stage,  StageNum)
```

You can compare positions requierd with the operations

```
select top(1) with ties ID, Stage, StageNum, Date
from (
  select t.ID ,t.StageNum, t.Date, stn.Stage, stn.spos, row_number() over(partition by ID order by t.StageNum) tpos
  from tbl t
  join (
     select StageNum, Stage, row_number() over(order by StageNum) spos
     from stages
  ) stn on stn.StageNum = t.StageNum
) t
where tpos=spos
order by row_number() over(partition by ID order by StageNum desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility without creating a table to records stages. We use `string_agg()` and then check that all the stages are present. We could do this without a CTE but we would have to run `string_agg` several times per row.

> ```
> create table c(
> ID int,
> Stage varchar(20),
> StageNum int,
> sDate Date);
> insert into c values
> (104,'Released',10,'2022-02-07'),
> (104,'Slab',  20,'2022-02-18'),
> (104,'Frame', 30,'2022-03-07'),
> (104,'Mechanicals',42,'2022-03-10'),
> (105,'Released',  10,'2022-02-07'),
> (105,'Slab',  20,'2022-02-18'),
> (106,'Released',10,'2022-02-07'),
> (106,'Slab',  20,'2022-02-18'),
> (106,'Frame', 30,'2022-03-04'),
> (106,'Cornice',   40,'2022-03-08');
> ```

> ```
> select * from c;
> ```
>
> ```
>  ID | Stage       | StageNum | sDate     
> --: | :---------- | -------: | :---------
> 104 | Released    |       10 | 2022-02-07
> 104 | Slab        |       20 | 2022-02-18
> 104 | Frame       |       30 | 2022-03-07
> 104 | Mechanicals |       42 | 2022-03-10
> 105 | Released    |       10 | 2022-02-07
> 105 | Slab        |       20 | 2022-02-18
> 106 | Released    |       10 | 2022-02-07
> 106 | Slab        |       20 | 2022-02-18
> 106 | Frame       |       30 | 2022-03-04
> 106 | Cornice     |       40 | 2022-03-08
> ```

> ```
> select
>   id,
>   string_agg(stageNUM,'-')
> from c
> group by id;
> ```

> ```
>  id | (No column name)
> --: | :---------------
> 104 | 10-20-30-42     
> 105 | 10-20           
> 106 | 10-20-30-40
> ```

> ```
> with stages as(
> select
>   id,
>   string_agg(stageNUM,'') s
> from c
> group by id
> )
> select
>   id,
>   case when s = '1020304042'
>     then 'Mechanicals'
>     when left(s,8) = '10203040'
>     then 'Cornice'
>     when left(s,6) = '102030'
>     then 'Frame'
>     when left(s,4) = '1020'
>     then 'Slab'
>     when left(s,2) = '10'
>     then 'Released'
>     else 'unknown' end Stage
> from stages
> ```

> ```
>  id | Stage  
> --: | :------
> 104 | Frame  
> 105 | Slab   
> 106 | Cornice
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81a8bd474bc00a2ff2fd35b0b681ebef)*

Comment: This is an interesting solution and I had never head of string_agg() before. I appreciate it!